# Navigating to a Bottom Tab Screen from a Single screen with a button Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a auth page and after the auth page, I basically navigate to a Tabbed application.

The problem is that bottom bar disappears once I click on tab.

Below is what my code looks like

```
sealed class ScreenM(val route: String) {
    object Landing: Screen("landingm")
    object Tab: Screen("tabm")
}

sealed class Screen(val route: String) {
    object PasswordLogin: Screen("passwordlogin")
    object TabBar: Screen("tabbar")
}

sealed class TabbarItem(var route: String, var icon: Int, var title: String) {
    object Home : TabbarItem("tabhome", R.drawable.ic_home_tab_icon, "Home")
    object Profile : TabbarItem("tabprofile", R.drawable.ic_profile_tab_icon, "Profile")
}
```

my application entry point is

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = ScreenM.Landing.route) {
        addLandingTopLevel(navController = navController)
        addTabBarTopLevel(navController = navController)
    }
}

private fun NavGraphBuilder.addLandingTopLevel(
    navController: NavController,
) {
    navigation(
        route = ScreenM.Landing.route,
        startDestination = Screen.Home.route
    ) {
        addPasswordLogin(navController)
    }
}
private fun NavGraphBuilder.addPasswordLogin(navController: NavController) {
    composable(route = Screen.PasswordLogin.route) {
        PasswordLoginView(navController)
    }
}

private fun NavGraphBuilder.addTabBarTopLevel(
    navController: NavController,
) {
    navigation(
        route = ScreenM.Tab.route,
        startDestination = Screen.TabBar.route
    ) {
        addTabBar(navController)
        addHome(navController)
        addProfile(navController)
    }
}

private fun NavGraphBuilder.addTabBar(navController: NavController) {

    composable(route = Screen.TabBar.route) {
        TabBarView(navController)
    }
}

private fun NavGraphBuilder.addHome(navController: NavController) {
    composable(route = TabbarItem.Home.route) {
        HomeView()
    }
}
private fun NavGraphBuilder.addProfile(navController: NavController) {
    composable(route = TabbarItem.Profile.route) {
        ProfileView()
    }
}
```

I am triggering the Tab like this

```
// ...
NavigationButton(buttonText = "Login", onBackPressed = {
    navController.popBackStack()
}) {
    navController.navigate(ScreenM.Tab.route)
}
// ...
```

Then my Tabbar is like

```
@Composable
fun TabBarView(navController: NavController) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomNavigationBar(navController) }
    ) {
    }
}
```

Then bottom navigation Bar is like this

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController) {
    val items = listOf(
        TabbarItem.Home,
        TabbarItem.Profile
    )
    BottomNavigation(
        backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
        contentColor = Color.Black
    ) {
        items.forEach { item ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = { Icon(painterResource(id = item.icon), contentDescription = item.title) },
                label = { Text(text = item.title) },
                selectedContentColor = Color.Red,
                unselectedContentColor = Color.Blue.copy(0.4f),
                alwaysShowLabel = true,
                selected = false,
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(item.route) {
                        // Pop up to the start destination of the graph to
                        // avoid building up a large stack of destinations
                        // on the back stack as users select items
                        navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
                            popUpTo(route) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                        }
                        // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                        // reselecting the same item
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see three routes: `Home` `Profile` `TabBar`, and `TabBarView` is only added inside one of them. When you switch tabs, the `TabBar` route disappears, as does your `TabBarView`. You need to add it inside each destination or move it outside the `NavHost`.

Comment: I don’t get what you suggesting. Would appreciate code samples please.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I tried what you suggested and The tabs are not changing. Tabs remain on selection but screens are not changing.

Comment: Please update your code to what have you tried

Comment: I just added this into the NavGraphBuilder of Home and Profile

`composable(route = TabbarItem.Home.route) {
        TabBarView(navController)
    }`

Comment: You can pass the current screen to each route and update `selected` argument accordingly

Comment: I do not understand. If you could help with sample code. I am a transitioning iOS developer. & trying to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Displaying `BottomNavigationBar` inside each tab

   1.1. Not sure what's `addTabBar` navigation route in your code, I don't think it's need, as looks like you only have two tabs: `TabbarItem.Home` and `TabbarItem.Profile`.

   1.2. You can add `BottomNavigationBar` inside each view, specifying the selected item. Inside `HomeView` it can look like this:

   ```
   BottomNavigationBar(navController, selectedTab = TabbarItem.Home)
   ```

   1.3. Depending on the selected tab, you need to select the needed item of `BottomNavigationBar`

   ```
   @Composable
   fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController, selectedTab: TabbarItem) {
       val items = listOf(
           TabbarItem.Home,
           TabbarItem.Profile
       )
       BottomNavigation(
           // ...
       ) {
           items.forEach { item ->
               BottomNavigationItem(
                   // ...
                   selected = selectedTab == item,
                   // ...
   ```
2. Having a single navigation bar outside of `NavHost`, you can find an example in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav)

Comment: addTabbar is the NavGraph that contains the TabBarView which is the parent View for all the Tab-items (Home, Profile)

Comment: While option 1 works I am just concerned because when you use the back button on the android phone, it just navigates back to all preceding tabs that were selected. I don't think that's the behaviour of a Tabbar.

Comment: @King for option 1 to work you need to use same logic as in documentation for option 2: they're popping current screen with `popUpTo`

Comment: As using option 2, I found that I'm using two separate navController, one for the root section which startDestination in SplashScreen and another is for bottomNav which start destination is HomeScreen generally. So my question is,, is double navController  safe without any issues??

Comment: @AIShakil yes, it should be safe. You may face some issues with builtin deep links, but I personally don't use this feature of `NavHost` and prefer to handle them manually anyway.